# Select link in a table with jsoup using Java code

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup, html-table

I need to get the download link in this table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img class="img" src="...path" /></td>
<td><a href="the file I want to download">File</a> - 
<a id="1569" class="tepLink" href="javascript:void(0);">[Click me]</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this is what I tried:

```
Element table = doc.select("table[cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" border=\"0\"]").first();
Element dwlLink = table.select("td:has(a)").first();
String absPath = dwlLink.attr("abs:href");
//use download manager to download from string absPath
```

I always get a "null object reference" so I must be wrong with that code, what should it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select all anchor tags and then get the first element in the Elements object.

```
    Elements anchorTags = doc.select("table[cellpadding=0][cellspacing=3][border=0] a");
    if(anchorTags.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(anchorTags.first());
    }
```

EDIT:

I changed the select method to include the cellpadding, cellspacing and border attributes since that seems like what you were after in one of your examples.

Also, the Element.first() method returns null if the Elements list is empty. Always check for null when calling that method to prevent NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Yes, that would work, if there is only one such table in the document.

Comment: Well there is only one table in the document you posted.

Comment: I did not post any table :) But you are right, it is always hard to guess what parts of such a CSS query need to be included to be specific enough. I think the OP gets the idea from your answer, this is why I voted up.

Comment: Sorry. On my first cup of coffee this morning. Still not fully booted. Yea parsing html is difficult to get right, especially when there is no clearly defined way to identify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`table.select("td:has(a)").first();` will select the first `<tr>` element that contains an anchor. It will not select the anchor `<a>` itself.

here is what you can do:

```
Element aEl = doc.select("table[cellpadding] td a").first();
```